# Mantener mi nariable "1009-1" en javascript porque cuando la llamo a una funcion se resta

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

estoy queriendo crear una vista con Codeigneiter 3, pero solo interactua la vista.php
Creo el html:

```
**<div class="tab-pane fade" id="web" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="web-tab">
     <div class="container-fluid"> 
                                                
     </div>
     <textarea class="col-lg-12" style="height: 150px" name="imagenes" id="imagenes"> 
     </textarea>     
</div>**
```

Y mi js es se activa al cargar la web, crea una lista de imagenes recuperadas con un Json:

```
**$("#web-tab").click(function () {
                    let aray = {};
                    var texto_web = "";
                    console.log("hola");
                    var imgwebdjuntos = <?= isset($this->producto['imagenes']) ? $this->producto['imagenes'] : ""; ?>;
                    var cont_w = 0;
                    $.each(imgwebdjuntos, function (index, valor) {
                        var subaray = {
                            "name": valor['name'],
                            "datetime": "",
                            "main": "assets/source/productos/" + valor['name'] + ".webp", //"main":"assets/source/productos/"+valor['name']+"-"+index+".webp",
                            "thumb": ""
                        };
                        texto_web += ` 
                                                                <div class="col" id="col_w` + cont_w + `">                                                                   
                                                                    <div class="image-container">
                                                                        <figure style="position: relative;"> 
                                                                            <a class="btn btn-danger mx-2" id="xborrar` + cont_w + `" style="position: absolute;opacity: 0.7;bottom: 5%;" data-item="` + valor['name'] + `" onclick="myFunction(col_w` + cont_w + ',' + cont_w + `)">borrar</a>
                                                                            <img src="` + valor['main'] + `" class="img-thumbnail rounded-lg" alt="Foto del usuario" style="max-width: 198px;min-width: 100px;">                                                                            
                                                                        </figure>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div> `;
                        cont_w++;
                        aray[valor['name']] = subaray;//aray[valor['name']+index]=subaray;
                    });
                    $("#imagenes").text(JSON.stringify(aray));
                    $("#my-images2").html(texto_web);
                });
            });//Fin del ready**
```

Y aca mi problema este es el metodo del boton borrar:

```
**function myFunction(x, y) {
                var aray = {};
                x.remove();                         
                aray = ($("#imagenes").val());
                console.log("JSON.parse", aray);
                console.log("y", y);
                $.each(aray, function (index, valor) {
                    if (index === y) {
                        delete aray[index];
                    }
                });
                console.log("delete", aray);
            }**
```

Este es el Json:

```
**{"1009-0":{"indice":0,"name":"1009-0","datetime":"","main":"assets/source/productos/1009-0.webp","thumb":""},"1009-1":{"indice":1,"name":"1009-1","datetime":"","main":"assets/source/productos/1009-1.webp","thumb":""},"1009-2":{"indice":2,"name":"1009-2","datetime":"","main":"assets/source/productos/1009-2.webp","thumb":""},"1009-3":{"indice":3,"name":"1009-3","datetime":"","main":"assets/source/productos/1009-3.webp","thumb":""},"1009-4":{"indice":4,"name":"1009-4","datetime":"","main":"assets/source/productos/1009-4.webp","thumb":""}}**
```

Como mi indice es "1009-0" al jalarlo a la funcion sale "1009" y no lo puedo comparar (valor.indice === y) le aplique .toString() pero siempre le llega a la funcion como si fuera una resta no cmo srting,
Gracias
Lo que deseo es borrar una imagen y luego armar un Json sin los datos de esa imagen

Comment: Hola Carlos, Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: simplifica el problema. Yo le he echado un visatzo y no tiene por que darte el problema que dices. Traza el valor de tu json y busca en que momento deja de ser un string. Si ocurre lo que dices sólo puede ser causado por un parseInt() fuera de lugar. Un saludo.